# How to use FFmpeg to adjust the audio pts of specific frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I shift the audio pts by using:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -af "asetpts=PTS+3/TB" output.mp4
```

But now, I only want to adjust the first of n audio frames (or 0 ~ n seconds).

I try to use select, enable=between(t, 0, n), etc.

Unfortunately, these methods do not work.

How should I modify the command?

Any help on this would be very appreciated.

Please let me know if you need additional details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [eval API](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation) functions to set the logic.

The expression will add an offset of 3 seconds for frames N=0 to 9, else preserve the input PTS.

`asetpts='if(lt(N,10),PTS+3/TB,PTS)'`

Comment: Hi Gran,

Thanks for your reply. It seams reasonable but the result only shows the frame which audio pts is greater than 3 by ffprobe. Do I miss something ?

Comment: Since the filter adds an offset of 3s to the first ten packets, it is reasonably expected that the earliest PTS will be 3 seconds.